# Can I replace my ISP provided router?

Tags: router

I have a Huawei LTE router model b2268h which was provided to me by the ISP.

The router is split into two devices, an indoor unit and an outdoor unit, the SIM card is installed in the outdoor unit.

Since installation, indoor unit was not providing good wireless coverage for devices (laptops and mobile phones) in my house,  so I bought a Google mesh router and connected it via ethernet cable to the indoor unit and that worked fine for two years. Recently the internet keeps disconnecting in the indoor unit and it is very slow.

Can I replace the indoor unit with some other better router or do I have to go back to my ISP and ask them to provide me with another one? I am not talking about the legal side of course, I am asking weather its technically possible to replace the indoor unit with some other better router from a company other then Huawei and connect it to the outdoor unit from Huawei and it will work fine with it?

Comment: Have you tried plugging that ethernet into a different router?

Comment: Looked up the product and it appears the two devices require each other, though I could not find specifics on the protocols it uses to communicate between them. Did you buy the modem/router or are they leased or included in the service? If the former, you can certainly try connecting a different device, but if the latter, you should talk to your ISP.

Comment: In some cases the ISP provided WiFi Modem can be configured in bridge mode.  It turns off WiFi and other router functions. You can then connect wherever router and WiFi hardware you wish.